# IndexError: tuple index out of range in python

Tags: python, json, image, pycharm, streamlit

I am making a movie recommendation system and I was trying to add images to the website using image paths from json (using tmdb api). And working in pycharm

I wrote the following code which gives me this error. I can't point out the error in my code though.

```py
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import requests

def fetch_poster(movie_id):
    response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{}%7D?api_key=0b22848a5f7f8b651a133c1966ea7784&language=en-US'.format(movie_id))
    data = response.json()
    print(data)
    return "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + data['poster_path']


def recommend(movie):
    movie_index = movies[movies['title'] == movie].index[0]
    distances = similarity[movie_index]
    movies_list = sorted(list(enumerate(distances)), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[1:6]

    recommended_movies = []
    recommended_movies_posters = []
    for i in movies_list:
        movie_id = i[0]
        recommended_movies.append(movies.iloc[i[0]].title)
        # fetch poster from API
        recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(i[movie_id]))
    return recommended_movies



movies_dict = pickle.load(open('movie_dict.pkl','rb'))
movies = pd.DataFrame(movies_dict)

similarity = pickle.load(open('similarity.pkl','rb'))

st.title('Movie Recommender System')

selected_movie_name = st.selectbox('how would you like to be contacted',movies['title'].values)

if st.button('Recommend'):
    names,posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)

    col1, col2, col3 = st.beta_columns(3)
    with col1:
        st.header("A cat")
        st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/cat.jpg")
    with col2:
        st.header("A cat")
        st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/cat.jpg")
    with col3:
        st.header("A cat")
        st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/cat.jpg")
```

(this is my code so far....after this i got the error shown below)

```
2023-06-28 20:04:46.963 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    movies_list = pickle.load(open('movies.pkl','rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'
2023-06-28 20:05:35.860 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\streaml
  File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\streaml
it\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    movies_list = pickle.load(open('movies.pkl','rb'))
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'
2023-06-30 13:25:58.077 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\streaml
it\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 38, in <module>
    names,posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 23, in recommend
    recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(i[movie_id]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
2023-06-30 13:32:10.582 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\streaml
it\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 38, in <module>
    names,posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 23, in recommend

    recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(i[movie_id]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
2023-06-30 13:34:07.739 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\streaml
it\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 39, in <module>
    names,posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 24, in recommend

    recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(i[movie_id]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
2023-06-30 13:34:11.087 Uncaught app exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\pycharmprojects\movie-recommender-system\venv\lib\site-packages\streaml
it\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 39, in <module>
    names,posters = recommend(selected_movie_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\movie-recommender-system\app.py", line 24, in recommend

    recommended_movies_posters.append(fetch_poster(i[movie_id]))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: How many elements does `i` have, and what is the value of `movie_id` ?

Comment: Python lists or tuples with a length of N where N is non-zero can be indexed by values in the inclusive range -N -> N-1 During development it's a good idea to use an assertion to ensure that this rule is adhered to

Comment: movie_id is taken from a database....it keeps changing based on movie selected

Comment: so where in the code is the error